# "xyz***" was unexpected at this time

Tags: git, github

I was trying to commit my code and got this error

```
xyz*** was unexpected at this time.
pre-commit: 
pre-commit: We've failed to pass the specified git pre-commit hooks as the `xyz***`
pre-commit: hook returned an exit code (1). If you're feeling adventurous you can
pre-commit: skip the git pre-commit hooks by adding the following flags to your commit:
pre-commit: 
pre-commit:   git commit -n (or --no-verify)
pre-commit: 
pre-commit: This is ill-advised since the commit is broken.
pre-commit:
```

NOTE: My code is in sync with the remote.

Comment: This looks more like a report than a question. The message seems self-explanatory, i.e. one of your pre-commit hooks failed. So what specifically are you asking? Also: what does hook `xyz` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from your pre-commit hook. Pre-commit hooks perform some checks on your code to prevent pushing code to remote unless it meets certain criteria. You can have a look at the pre-commit hook on where your code is returning exit code of 1(failing).

Of course, you can go ahead and commit the code with

```
git commit -n
```

but that defeats the purpose of making the pre-commit hook.